# apostrophe issue with appendTo

Tags: javascript, apostrophe, appendto

Below are the two codes that I tried:

```
$( "<li class='item' id='item' name='"+infoitem+"'>"+ title +"</li>" ).appendTo( "#sortable" );
$( "<li class='item' id='item' name='"+infoitem+"'/>").html(title).appendTo( "#sortable" );
```

title containing apostrophe throws an error and it breaks the code...

How do I filter the text with \' and then re-add it as an acceptable html with the apostrophe?

Any suggestions would be great.

EDIT:

I got an working example of why its not working
http://jsfiddle.net/cowmoohard/bxxmhe03/4/

In the original post I forgot to mention that the appendTo is in a function and it takes a string of characters included space. Please see the example above. Just edit it with ' in the string and then it'll stop working.

Comment: use `.attr` to set attributes.

Comment: The 2nd one works just fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/bxxmhe03/  though `.text` is probably more appropriate than `.html` in this case if `title` is just text and not html entities.

Comment: I switched .html out with attr... and its not working. I used the 2nd example and its not working when only have 1 apostrophe. Not sure why its working on JSFiddle and not on localhost..

Comment: @cowmoohard Can you reproduce that in jsfiddle, because I can't?  It works fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/bxxmhe03/1/

Comment: Having a headache trying to get it onto a jsfiddle. It retrieves place.name from google map v3 and I set it as title then pass it to a function as user onClick the infowindow... if title is "Tony's Shop" wth apostrophe.. it'll break. Gonna see if I can get it on JSFiddle or maybe some other alternative

Comment: @JamesMontagne I got the JSFiddle up and running... http://jsfiddle.net/cowmoohard/bxxmhe03/4/ Please help!

Comment: @cowmoohard The issue is not in the code you posted at all, it is in the creation of the button.  The apostrophe is creating a problem there.  Dont' use inline onclick, instead attach it with jquery.

Comment: @JamesMontagne Inside infowindow on google map v3, I almost required to use a button for user to interact.. If I don't use button.... whats another way about it? Could you clarify a little bit on attach it with jquery? Would user still able to click on something?

Comment: @JamesMontagne Actually I think I know what your talking about... So I shold use jquery act as an type=submit instead? now.. I gotta.. test this more.. seems to be returning blank http://jsfiddle.net/cowmoohard/bxxmhe03/5/

Comment: @cowmoohard Please have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use ' for javascript and obligatory use " for HTML. It will looks like:

```
$('<li class="item" id="item" name="' + infoitem + '">' + title + '</li>').appendTo('#sortable');
    $('<li class="item" id="item" name="' + infoitem + '"/>').html(title).appendTo('#sortable');
```

Edit1:

```
 var addedTitle="I'am a supe long string".replace('\'', '&#39;');
```

this is in your fiddler code.

Edit2: If you need to replace multiple things:

```
    String.prototype.replaceAll = function (searchvalue, newvalue) {
    return this.split(searchvalue).join(newvalue);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your fiddle illuminates the actual issue:

```
content = "<input type='button' value='Add' onclick='addme(\"" + addedTitle + "\")' />"

document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = content;
```

The problem is that the above code will generate the following:

```
<input type='button' value='Add' onclick='addme("some'string")' />
```

You'll notice this has a single quote inside of your `onclick` which is single quoted.  This is what is breaking.  You can escape the single quote with `\`.

However, a better approach would be to get rid of the inline `onclick` and do it this way:

```
var input = $("<input type='button' value='Add'/>").click(function(){
     addme(addedTitle); 
});

$("#display").append(input);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bxxmhe03/6/

Comment: That works too. I'll gave it an upvote. Other solution is a much faster one as it replaces the original string so rest of my function calls wouldn't have any issues... stupid apostrophes... :P Thanks again looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
   $( "#sortable" ).append("<li class='item' id='item' name='"+infoitem+"'>"+ title +"</li>");
```

Comment: Still giving me the same result.. I'm trying to get on JSfiddle for it to work. Maybe alternative of finding apostrophe in the code and give it a new value or something? Not sure why my code is breaking...